# Writing very big data chunk synchroneously with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, io

I'm trying to write a very big data chunk (resulting from JSON.stringify) into a file. It must be synchroneous, because I would like to save it during the process:exit event. However, when using fs.writeFileSync(), Node throws with this message :

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I've tried fs.createWriteStream(), but it does not seems to work. This code output 0 bytes with medium data amount, and throws the same error with large.

Comment: This is why streams for, can you explain why fs.createWriteStream() failed?

Comment: @Mustafa I don't know. The final file does not contains anything.

Comment: @NisonMaël what length of your string is? You sure, that FS operation failed and not `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @elmigranto I've just checked, the fail seems to happen inside JSON.stringify. That's strange, previous tests were failing inside writeFileSync... Do you know any way to increase node memory limit ? Top seems to say that I'm only using 33% of the total memory size

Comment: @NisonMaël I personally never have faced such problem, that was only a guess. Anyway, [that link](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/11/escape-the-1-4gb-v8-heap-limit-in-node-js/) seems pretty up-to-date, but you probably will need your own Node build. This two could also be helpful: [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nodejs/VZe-NKPwp7k), [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/BQ5dSm8lITQ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in JSON.stringify. Data were too big to be stored in a unique javascript string.

I solved this issue by serializing one property per line (so there is X calls to JSON.stringify, where X is the number of properties in my object). My deserializer rebuild the object by adding every properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a 'pump'. Something like http://elegantcode.com/2011/04/06/taking-baby-steps-with-node-js-pumping-data-between-streams/ That will relieve your kernel buffers and they will not have to hold all the text all the time.

Comment: I'm not sure, the source of my data is a string, there is only one stream involved